# Amcharts Only Scrolling ( no zooming )

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

**Amchart (bar chart)** with **scrolling** has some **zooming effect** also when the scroll bar reaches to the end. How can i **disable this zooming effect** and have only scrolling.

Here's the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JSTQW/2/)**

**ScrollBar Settings:**

```
"maxSelectedSeries": 10,
"mouseWheelScrollEnabled": true,
"chartScrollbar": {
    "graphType": "column",
    "resizeEnabled": false,
    "scrollbarHeight": 21,
    "scrollDuration": 0,
    "updateOnReleaseOnly": true
}
```

PS: I cannot disable the scrolling through mouse.

Comment: All that I can come up with is setting "mouseWheelScrollEnabled" to false. Then they have to use the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following property:

```
"mouseWheelZoomEnabled": false,
```